# How to solve Apple Match-O Linker Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal

**I had downloaded the sample code from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK.
But it gives me following error.
I am unable to solve this. If anyone know, please help me.**

> Apple Match-O Linker Error clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
>   ld: 242 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Comment: I have prior experience with the same error when i use same variable name in different .m files

Answer (score 0):

## it can resolved by adding following lib.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your download folder
2. Open terminal, type `cd` then drag the folder in terminal
3. Then type `pod install` and hit enter and run the xcode.workspaces

It will solve your problem.